# Firebase Javascript SDK browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, firebase, sdk

Why I can't find any information about browser compatibility for Firebase Javascript SDK?

Comment: Firebase works in most browsers. Are you having problems with a specific browser?

Comment: I'm integrating it, now. It'd be nice to have browser support data.

Comment: He is likely asking because of errors like these I am seeing in Sentry: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK.    browser = Firefox 56.0,  browser.name = Firefox, os.name = Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because Firebase uses standard technologies, which should be supported by all modern browsers. HTTP, AJAX, XMPP, Web Push Protocol, Web Sockets (actually i am not sure about the web sockets). 
You can check which browsers are compatible with these technologies if you are developing for something specific.